# Decrease in electrical conductivity due to the increase in oxygen content

Tags: theoretical-chemistry

I am just wondering why there is increase in electrical conductivity of some materials with the decrease in oxygen, or vice versa. When Graphene oxide (which is an insulator) is reduced to rGO (reduced graphene oxide), the rGO becomes electrically conductive. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not limited to oxygen, it is similar with graphite fluoride. They bind to electrons which are not then available for conductivity.

Comment: In many metal oxides the oxygen vacancy is a charged and mobile species.